# Make Cordova wait for async hook to finish

Tags: node.js, cordova, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

In my Cordova project, I have a hook which does RequireJS optimization (r.js) on `after_prepare`. That optimization is inherently asynchronous, so my hook code returns before all optimization is fully finished.

For example, this causes issues when running `cordova run browser`: On the first page load, optimization has not finished yet and the site looks broken.

Is there a way to make the Cordovoa build process to block until a certain hook fires a callback? Or can the optimizer be run in a blocking/sync way?

An alternative I could think of is using a different process for optimization and busy-wait in the main for it to finish, but that looks like an overkill and bad practice to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in promise module to block Cordova from proceeding until the hook has resolved. 
Something along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var deferral;

function doSomethingAsync(){
    somethingAync
        .success(function(){
            deferral.resolve();
        })
        .fail(function(err){
            deferral.reject(err);
        });
}

module.exports = function(ctx) {
    deferral = ctx.requireCordovaModule('q').defer();
    doSomethingAsync();
    return deferral.promise;
};
```

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I was looking for. I somehow failed to find this in the docs myself...

Comment: `requireCordovaModule('q')` does not work, I get `Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.`

Comment: In cordova version >= 9 use at the beginning `const q = require('q')` and then assign `deferral` with `deferral = q.defer()`

Comment: this answer was written 4 years ago for `cordova-android@6`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `context`, you can simply return a Promise from within the `module.exports` function

```js
module.exports = context => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
    });
};
```

I tested and it works. The problem arises because in Cordova versions => 9 you cannot use `context.requireCordovaModule('q')`

If you don't want to use Promise, just do

```js
module.exports = context => {
    var deferral = require('q').defer();
    doSomethingAsync(() => {
      deferral.resolve();
    });
    return deferral.promise;
};
```